# How to combine rows with specific names in R

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

I have a dataframe with some repeated rows from a loop:

```
                     v1     v2     v3    v4
  Number              1     2      3     5
  Index               0     0      0     0
  Number.1            1     2      3     5
  Index.1             0     0      0     0
  Number.2            1     2      3     5
  Index.2             0     0      0     0
  Number.3            1     2      3     5
  Index.3             0     0      0     0
  Number.4            1     2      3     5
  Index.4             0     0      0     0
  Number.5            1     2      3     5
  Index.5             0     0      0     0
```

I want to append all rows that have "Number" as a single row of values each in one different column

```
                      v1     v2     v3   v4    v5     v6     v7    v8
  Number              1     2      3     5      1     2      3     5   etc
```

I haven't found any simple way to do it, although it seems easy.
I tried with dplyr like this with no success:

```
  df[,rownames(df)%in%(grep("Number*", rownames(df))]
```

Comment: I think you need the `,` after `c(t(df[rownames(df)%in%(grep("Number*", rownames(df)),]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a rather convoluted `dplyr` solution - explanation in in-line comments.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(row_name = rownames(.)) %>% # Add a new column with the row names
  filter(grepl("Number", row_name)) %>% # filter against a match for 'Number'
  select(-row_name) %>% # Get rid of that column
  t() %>% # Transpose
  map(unlist, use.names = F) %>% # Flatten
  as.data.frame() %>% # Convert to a df so we can change the row name later
  `colnames<-`(paste0("v", seq(1:ncol(.)))) %>%  # Add colnames to your format
  `rownames<-`("Number") # Add the row name
```

Result:

```
       v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10 v11 v12 v13 v14 v15 v16 v17 v18
Number  1  2  3  1  2  3  1  2  3   1   2   3   1   2   3   1   2   3
```

Answer (score 2):

We take the transpose and concatenate (`c`) to get a `vector`

```
i1 <-  rownames(df)%in%(grep("Number(\\.\\d)*", rownames(df), value = TRUE))
v1 <- c(t(df[i1, ]))
```

NOTE: `grep` returns the index, so there is no need to do `%in%` again to match with the rownames

```
i2 <- grep("Number(\\.\\d)*", rownames(df))
```

would be enough to subset

```
v2 <- c(t(df[i2, ]))
```

It is better to have it as a vector and not as a data.frame.  If we really need a single row data.frame with as many columns

```
as.data.frame.list(v1)
```

NOTE2: Changed the pattern slightly to match the `.` followed by digit if any.  In the OP's code, it would check `Number*`, i.e. 0 or more 'r' (though it worked in the data)

Comment: This works like a charm! I tought it would be easier to do, but it works as intended